# Merge "one-to-one" dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have got  two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = 
{'Invoice' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Value' : [10, 25, 40, 10, 15]}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data =
{'Invoice' : [2, 3, 5, 2], 'Value' : [25, 11, 15,25], 'TestData':["A",'B','C','D']})
```

I've already merged them and get df3:

```
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on=["Invoice","Value"], right_on=["Invoice","Value"])
```

Df3 output:

```
   Invoice    Value   TestData
0      2    25        A
1      2    25        D
2      5    15        C
```

My question is how to get merged dataframe with "one-to-one" (I mean - when invoice number 2 occurs only once (or generally less) in one of two dataframes, then don't create another row with invoice number 2 in merged dataframe). I'd like to get something like this:

```
   Invoice    Value   TestData
0      2    25        A
1      5    15        C
```

or this:

```
   Invoice    Value   TestData
0      2    25        D
1      5    15        C
```

I tried only left and right merging, but this doesn't work - there are always two rows with invoice number 2.

Thank you,
Jarek

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with specify columns names, parameter `keep='last'` is for last duplicated row:

```
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(["Invoice","Value"])
#same as
#df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(["Invoice","Value"], keep='first')
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2, on=["Invoice","Value"])
print (df3)
   Invoice  Value TestData
0        2     25        A
1        5     15        C
```

---

```
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(["Invoice","Value"], keep='last')
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2, on=["Invoice","Value"])
print (df3)
   Invoice  Value TestData
0        2     25        D
1        5     15        C
```

EDIT:

If need groupby by all rows, is necessary add new column for uniqueness:

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby(['Invoice','Value']).cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby(['Invoice','Value']).cumcount()

print (df1)
   Invoice  Value  g
0        1     10  0
1        2     25  0
2        3     40  0
3        4     10  0
4        5     15  0

print (df2)
   Invoice TestData  Value  g
0        2        A     25  0
1        3        B     11  0
2        5        C     15  0
3        2        D     25  1

df3=pd.merge(df1,df2, on=["Invoice","Value", "g"]).drop('g', axis=1)
print (df3)
   Invoice  Value TestData
0        2     25        A
1        5     15        C
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I can't drop these rows  from df2 because I need them - doubled values, in this case, are not errors. Let's say df1 contains invoices subsetted by one category and df2 by another. At the moment it might be problem with lack of the invoice in df1, so I can't drop duplicates. Another reasnon I can't drop them is that (as I think) I won't be able to filter source df1 and df2 by those values which were used in merging using something like this :  `df1[(~df1.Invoice.isin(df3.Invoice))&(~df1.Value.isin(df3.Value))]` because that isn't source df but dropped. @Zulfiqaar

Comment: Give me a sec, I have an idea.

Comment: Thank you very much! What a smart solusion! I have learned a lot from this. I clicked "This answer is useful" but I have no reputation, so thats all I can do:/

Comment: Thank you - I didn't noticed it:/

Comment: Thanks for this nugget of gold @jezrael !

Answer (score 2):

You can try a deduplication method by specific columns:

```
df3.drop_duplicates(subset="Invoice")

   Invoice  Value TestData
0        2     25        A
2        5     15        C
```

For more information:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html